# command to compare line by line for two program

Tags: file, compare, jython

Is there is command in jython which can compare line by line between two files and display the non-matching record.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want this in jython? What's wrong with 'diff'?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [diffj](http://www.incava.org/projects/java/diffj/index.html) ? It's a Java implementation of diff, and consequently available in Jython.